# Comparing labels of connected components in two images

Tags: python, image, type-conversion, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

I have a 32 bit image with multiple connected components with different labels (say 3 labels for example). Let us also assume that these 3 label values are 316067, 213676 and 1000 respectively. For some reason, I have to convert this image to 16-bit. Of course, after I do the conversion, the labels get mapped to 16-bit range. Let's say that these labels are mapped to 3000, 14000 and 1000 respectively (I know that in my images after conversion, the labels which were already within 16 bit range do not get mapped to any new number). My goal is to find all such labels which were changed from the 32-bit image to the 16-bit image while mapping. In the above example, I want to find the following.

1) Labels 1 and 2 were mapped to a new label value.
2) label 1 was mapped from 316067 to 3000 and label 2 was mapped from 213676 to 14000.

This becomes challenging for me because I have hundreds of such 32-bit images which need conversion to 16 bit images and the changed labels need to be read out. Also in each image, I have thousands of labels.

What is the most suitable and efficient way to implement this? Is there any routine in Python that can do this? Can someone please point me to a code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to develop an answer but your question is unclear and what I want to say doesn't format up or fit well in a comment so I will start with a partial answer and edit/develop it as you clarify...

You don't say your image is single channel, but as you give the 3 labels as 316067, 213676 and 1000, I presume single channel. Correct?

Let's synthesize a sample image:

```
im = np.arange(0,65536*65536,8192,dtype=np.uint32).reshape(1024,-1)
```

That gives `im` as 1024x512 pixels and values as:

```
   array(
   [[         0,       8192,      16384, ...,    4177920, 4186112],
   [   4194304,    4202496,    4210688, ...,    8372224,  8380416],
   ...,
   [4282384384, 4282392576, 4282400768, ..., 4286562304, 4286570496],
   [4286578688, 4286586880, 4286595072, ..., 4290756608, 4290764800],
   [4290772992, 4290781184, 4290789376, ..., 4294950912, 4294959104]],
   dtype=uint32)
```

And it gives the number of unique labels/colours as:

```
len(np.unique(im))                                                                                                                                                                                       
524288
```

So, is that representative? And now how do you currently get to a 16-bit image? And why?

Comment: Thank you @Mark Setchell. Yes, the image that you created is representative of the type of images that I have. Let me the change the question to the following. Let's say I want to convert all those labels which are not in  16 bit range to 16 bit range while making sure that it is not one of the 16 bit labels already present in the image. Then I want to get a map of which label got converted to what (including the ones that were already in 16 bit range and were not changed)

Comment: Could you clarify what technique/function you have been using to date as alluded to in your question please?

Comment: Also what do you mean by a **map** exactly? Another image or a CSV - I mean what does a map look like?